# search and replace between two files -post#2

Tags: regex, perl

I need to replace a variable in one file with information/regex found in another file. For example, I need to grab the first string/variable (that starts with MSTRG) from each row in file1:

```
MSTRG.5734  MSTRG.5734  509 -4  0   -14 0   0
MSTRG.19266 MSTRG.19266 842 -4  0   -12 0   0
MSTRG.26588 MSTRG.26588 196 5   0   12  0   0
```

and use this to search in file2 that will look something like this:

```
Chr1    StringTie   transcript  24039360    24041181    1000    -   .   gene_id "MSTRG.5734"; transcript_id "MSTRG.5734.1"; 
Chr1    StringTie   transcript  24039810    24040595    1000    -   .   gene_id "MSTRG.5734"; transcript_id "Transcript:AT1G64700.1"; ref_gene_id "Gene:AT1G64700"
Chr1    StringTie   exon    24040560    24041181    1000    -   .   gene_id "MSTRG.19266"; transcript_id "MSTRG.19266.1"; exon_number "2"; 
Chr1    StringTie   exon    24040560    24041181    1000    -   .   gene_id "MSTRG.26588"; transcript_id "MSTRG.26588.1"; exon_number "2"; 
Chr1    StringTie   transcript  24039810    24040595    1000    -   .   gene_id "MSTRG.26588"; transcript_id "Transcript:AT5G41000.1"; ref_gene_id "Gene:AT5G41000";
```

Ideally when e.g. `MSTRG.5734` is found on a line in file2 that also contains the string e.g. `Gene:AT1G64700`, it will grab the information `Gene:AT1G64700` and replace `MSTRG.5734` in file1. So, every `MSTRG` on each row in file1 is unique and it will theoretically match a unique Gene in file2. If it does not match a Gene then I need the original row in file1 to be maintained.

File1 output should then look like:

```
    Gene:AT1G64700  MSTRG.5734  509 -4  0   -14 0   0
    MSTRG.19266 MSTRG.19266 842 -4  0   -12 0   0
    Gene:AT5G41000  MSTRG.26588 196 5   0   12  0   0
```

My current perl code is:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use vars qw($outfile @id $mstrg $gene);

open(SEARCH, $ARGV[0]) or die "Couldn't open $ARGV[0]: $!";
open(FILE, $ARGV[1]) or die "Couldn't open $ARGV[1]: $!";
$outfile = "testout.txt";
open (OUT, ">$outfile") || die "Can't open $outfile for creation: $!\n";

my %mstrg;

while (<SEARCH>) {
chomp;
if (/^MSTRG/) {
    chomp $_;
    @id = split (/\t/, $_);
        $mstrg{$id[1]}.="$id[1]";
 }
}
while (<FILE>) # {@ffn=<FILE>};
{
chomp ($gene=$_);
    if ($mstrg =~ /$gene/) {
    print OUT "$id[1]\t$id[2]";}
    else {
        #print OUT "$_\n";
            } 
next;
        }           

close FILE;
```

This is unfortunately where I get stuck and not sure how to proceed?
Thanks for any help given, appreciated and apologies for the previous post where I did not include any code to those that saw.

Answer (score 2):

I would do this somewhat like:

```
use 5.014;               #needed min 5.014 because the /r modifier
use warnings;
use Path::Tiny '0.077';  #added the min. req. version

my $file1='file1.txt';
my $file2='file2.txt';

my %mstmap = map { split /\s+/, s/.*?gene_id\s*"\s*(MSTRG\.\d+).*ref_gene_id\s*"\s*(Gene:\w+)".*/$1 $2/r }
             grep { /ref_gene_id.*Gene:/ } path($file2)->lines({chomp => 1});
path($file1)->edit_lines( sub { s/^(MSTRG\.\d+)/exists($mstmap{$1}) ? $mstmap{$1} : $1/e });
```

for your input files produces

```
Gene:AT1G64700  MSTRG.5734  509 -4  0   -14 0   0
MSTRG.19266 MSTRG.19266 842 -4  0   -12 0   0
Gene:AT5G41000 MSTRG.26588 196 5   0   12  0   0
```

It create a hash for the pairs: `MSTRG.number` => `Gene:String` (from the `file2`), and using the [Path::Tiny](https://metacpan.org/pod/Path::Tiny) module editing fucntion doing the replaces in the `file1`.

After @Borodin comments the above could be reduced to:

```
use 5.014;
use warnings;
use Path::Tiny '0.077';

my $file1='f1';
my $file2='f2';

my %mstmap = map {
    /.*?gene_id\s*"\s*(MSTRG\.\d+).*ref_gene_id\s*"\s*(Gene:\w+).*/
} path($file2)->lines({chomp => 1});
path($file1)->edit_lines( sub { s/^(MSTRG\.\d+)/exists($mstmap{$1}) ? $mstmap{$1} : $1/e });
```

Comment: Wow @jm666.  Getting an error `Odd number of elements in hash assignment at ./test.pl line 12. (i.e. grep...)
Can't locate object method "edit_lines" via package "Path::Tiny" at ./test.pl line 13.`

Comment: Thanks though, I will put a bit more effort to see if I can figure out what that error is getting at.

Comment: I don't think I have it installed :)

Comment: Thanks @jm666, I'll work on that and see where I can get.

Comment: `map { split /\s+/, s/.*?gene_id\s*"\s*(MSTRG\.\d+).*ref_gene_id\s*"\s*(Gene:\w+)".*/$1 $2/r }` is generally written `map { /.*?gene_id\s*"\s*(MSTRG\.\d+).*ref_gene_id\s*"\s*(Gene:\w+)".*/ }`. That way there isn't any need for the `grep` either.

Comment: @Borodin Ah yes. The result of the matching operator are the matches itself. Again learned a new thing. Thank you.

Comment: @jm666: Specifically in list context, `m//` returns an empty list if it fails, or the captures in numerical order if it succeeds. If there are no captures then it returns `(1)`.

Answer (score 2):

There's no need to write impregnable code to achieve the result you want

This program reads through `$file2` building hash `%mstrg` from all the lines that contain both an `MSTRG.` and a `Gene:` string. It then creates a regex in `$re` that will match any one of the `MSTR.` strings found

`$file1` is opened, and that regex is used to replace any of the hash keys with the corresponding hash value it appears at the start of the line. The line is then printed

It isn't clear whether the first two fields of `file1.txt` are always the same, but I've opted to alter only the first field

I've used the `autodie` pragma to avoid having to explicitly check for success of any file IO operations

The program prints the output to STDOUT, so you can redirect it wherever you like on the command line

```perl
use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use autodie;

my ( $file1, $file2 ) = @ARGV;

my %mstrg;

{
    open my $fh, '<', $file2;

    while ( <$fh> ) {
        $mstrg{$1} = $2 if /"(MSTRG.\d+)".*"(Gene:\w+)"/;
    }
}

my $re = join '|', sort { length $b <=> length $a } keys %mstrg;

open my $fh, '<', $file1;

while ( <$fh> ) {
    s/^($re)\b/$mstrg{$1}/;
    print;  
}
```

#### output

```
Gene:AT1G64700  MSTRG.5734  509 -4  0   -14 0   0
MSTRG.19266 MSTRG.19266 842 -4  0   -12 0   0
Gene:AT5G41000 MSTRG.26588 196 5   0   12  0   0
```

Comment: Thank you @Borodin - this is code at my level obviously.  I am getting the following error that I am unfamiliar with - wondering whether you know what is going on, otherwise I will endeavour to figure it out. 'Can't open '<undef>' for reading: 'No such file or directory'`  It is referring to this line of your code `open my $fh, '<', $file2;`  I have defined the $files previously so...

Comment: @jnorth: As it stands it uses the same scheme as your own code: the paths to *file1* and *file2* are command-line parameters. I'd guess you have passed no parameters.

Comment: Gee wiz, don't I feel silly - I took that out after screwing around with the code so much and didn't think to put it back in...thanks again @Borodin!

Comment: @jnorth: You shouldn't need to do any more than just copy my code and run it.